# Elastic beanstalk and Visual Studio Online

Tags: deployment, msbuild, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, azure-devops

Is there any way to deploy build from VSO direct to Elastic Beanstalk?
I have working build of .Net Core application and I can easy deploy it from AWS Toolkit, but don't know it is possibile from VSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the deployment tool to automate deployments to Elastic Beanstalk.

1. Set up an [on premise build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)
2. Prepare environment (e.g. install AWS Toolkit for VS)
3. Call awsdeploy.exe tool to deploy via Command Line build step/task (e.g. Tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\Deployment Tool\awsdeploy.exe, Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory), Arguments: ElasticBeanstalkDeploymentSample.txt)

More information about deployment tool, you can refer to: [Deploying Elastic Beanstalk Applications in .NET Using the Deployment Tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/deploy_NET_standalone_tool.html)

Comment: So no direct deploy method without 3rd machine?

Comment: @BLuM Yes, because the awsdeploy tool isn't installed on the Hosted Build agent.